# MapReduce job starts after 10 min with lag time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I have this query `SELECT COUNT(*) from table`;

When I run this in Hive, I get something like the below and without a job ID.  And when I check the MapReduce jobs running, I do not see any running job. But, after 10 mins, I see that there is a running job. I don't know what's wrong and how to fix it.

I want MapReduce job to run immediately after the hive query.

I see following output on the Hive prompt:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1                                                                                                                                               
Launching Job 1 out of 1                                                                                                                                             
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1                                                                                                                
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes): set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>                                                                                                                 
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers: set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>                                                                                                                              
In order to set a constant number of reducers: set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
```

Comment: This sounds normal. How are you checking which mapreduce jobs are running? There's a bit of lag in the ResourceManager web ui.

Comment: I check in the job tracker and the command line log

Comment: Does your mapreduce job runs late and not soon after your start the hive query ?

Comment: Well if you are running Hive in VM then this behavior is kind of normal it takes a bit of time to do the set up and all.
Also if the input directory has many small files then also it takes a bit of time to set up the job.

Comment: I am not running on VM, its on a 16 clusters and the input directory has 20 files each of 50GB